# Highchart border rendering bug when hover

Tags: javascript, svg, highcharts

I have a Highcharts with `type: "column", stacking "normal"`. And when I hover blocks from the chart I need to show a border. So I set the next settings:

```
  ...
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
      groupPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 10,
      pointPadding: 0,
      states: {
        hover: {
          brightness: 0,
          borderColor: 'black'
        }
      }
    }
  }, ...
```

But when I hover block there is a problem with border - it  overlapped by neighbours blocks, and the border isn't fully visible.

Maybe the Highcharts has some additional setting to avoid this bug, or maybe it's possible to increase z-index of hovered element?

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rvk0gc9r):

Comment: I have posted this issue on Highcharts github, thank you for reporting the problem: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5670

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grzegorz Blachliński](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5418042/grzegorz-blachli%C5%84ski), thank You very much! I found a few solutions on that github topic.

They are here: http://jsfiddle.net/LLo7324r/ `,` http://jsfiddle.net/rvk0gc9r/6/